# How to use "cv2.estimateAffine3D" correctly, to align two 3d coordinate systems?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I have to align two 3d coordinate systems and I have 32 coordinates of points in the real world for each coordinate system.

I already know that I have to calculate the translation and the rotation and I (think) that I also understand what the calculation is. Because some smart people already had solve this problem I just want to use openCV for this and I asked the aiChatBot of how to do this calculation without and with openCV.

But I think using "cv2.estimateAffine3D" looks right.

Maybe some can just give me an example how to use it correctly?
**At the moment the code with example I have from the aiChatBot looks like this:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Define the coordinates of the three points in the first coordinate system
p1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3]], dtype=np.float32)
p2 = np.array([[4, 5, 6]], dtype=np.float32)
p3 = np.array([[7, 8, 9]], dtype=np.float32)

# Define the coordinates of the three points in the second coordinate system
q1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3]], dtype=np.float32)
q2 = np.array([[5, 6, 7]], dtype=np.float32)
q3 = np.array([[9, 10, 11]], dtype=np.float32)

# Calculate the affine transformation that aligns the two coordinate systems
T = cv2.estimateAffine3D(p1, p2, p3)

# Reshape the point arrays to 2D or 3D
q1_reshaped = q1.reshape(1, -1, 3)
q2_reshaped = q2.reshape(1, -1, 3)
q3_reshaped = q3.reshape(1, -1, 3)

# Apply the transformation to the second coordinate system
q1_aligned = cv2.transform(q1_reshaped, T)
q2_aligned = cv2.transform(q2_reshaped, T)
q3_aligned = cv2.transform(q3_reshaped, T)

# Print the transformed points
print(q1_aligned)
print(q2_aligned)
print(q3_aligned)
```

**the error I get is :**

error: OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'transform'

> Overload resolution failed:
>
> - m is not a numerical tuple
> - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'm

**the answer form the aiChatBot to solve this is:**
"It looks like the error you are experiencing is caused by passing an incorrect argument to the cv2.transform function. The cv2.transform function expects a 2D or 3D point array as the first argument and a 3x3 or 3x4 transformation matrix as the second argument, but you are passing a 1D point array and a 3x3 or 3x4 transformation matrix as arguments.

To fix this error, you need to pass a 2D or 3D point array as the first argument to the cv2.transform function. You can do this by reshaping the 1D point arrays q1, q2, and q3 using the np.reshape function, as follows:"

but there we come in a loop because this "solution" is already in the code.

So I do not really find any information about that. Can anybody help me with this?

cheers!

I want to align two coordinate systems.

Comment: What's the shape of T? Also have a look at open3D, which might have better aupport for 3D stuff.

Comment: According to [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga393164aa54bb9169ce0a8cc44e08ff22) the second parameter of `cv2.transform` should be "transformation 2x2 or 2x3 floating-point matrix". The output of [`cv2.estimateAffine3D`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga396afb6411b30770e56ab69548724715) is "transformation matrix 3×4...". And you seem to be passing that directly to `cv2.transform`. That doesn't satisfy the documented requirements. | The error message is a bit odd, but that might be a peculiarity of the wrapper codegen.

Comment: "answer form the aiChatBot" -- you're probably better asking random people you meet on the street, at least then there'd be some chance they actually understand what they're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

estimateAffine3D expects only two matrices.
Try:

```py
T = cv2.estimateAffine3D(np.asarray([p1, p2, p3]), np.asarray([q1, q2, q3]))
```